# Determining Scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

With this code i want see 200x200 window with 3 items. The 2nd or middle item with scrollbar, couldn't stretch to it's full size when maximize the window. "I forgot to tell that i want that scrollviewer with exact height size(such as 120*) when window is in normal. And if the window is stretched then i want to stretch all the items with it's "auto" size (means i want to show full of scrollviewer's items)." How to solve?

```
<Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="Hi" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="HI"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="HI" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="HI" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="HI" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Hello&#10;Hello&#10;Hello&#10;"/>
    </Grid>
```

Please see this image:

[image]

Or go to http://i42.tinypic.com/10r7994.png for full size image.

Comment: Please try the answer left by @LPL. In my opinion, that is a much better WPF answer, rather than setting exact `Width` and/or `Height` values... this approach is better suited to WinForms or other older technologies.

Comment: I forgot to tell that i want that scrollviewer with exact height size(such as 120*) when window is in normal. And if the window is stretched then i want to stretch all the items with it's "auto" size (means i want to show full of scrollviewer's items). Need help please

Comment: Oh no i can't post with picture cause i haven't enough reputation score. Can you please see this image below? i42.tinypic.com/10r7994.png

Comment: Somebody Answer to The posted Picture Please??

Comment: You keep mentioning 120* as an exact height... 120* is a *relative* height, not an exact height. Do you mean 120 pixels?

Comment: I know 120* is the relative height. Sorry for my misspelling. But now you made clear my question. The problem is when i using exact size(such as 120) all the contents in that middle row is not showing all the item with its row. Also when i using relative size(such as 120*) the above items not showing with the default window size(cause it must shown with its default).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Height="*"` to use remaining space for middle item:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that i want that scrollviewer with exact height size(such as 120*) when window is in normal. And if the window is stretched then i want to stretch all the items with it's "auto" size (means i want to show full of scrollviewer's items). Need help please

Comment: Somebody Answer to The posted Picture Please??

Answer (score 0):

You should set MinHeight and MinWidth of ScrollViewer.
and using Element bind the Height and Width of ScrollViewer of Window's Height and Width.

Like-- 
MinHeight="120" MinWidth="120"
Height="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=Wind}"

Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=Wind}"

it should work.

Comment: I forgot to tell that i want that scrollviewer with exact height size(such as 120*) when window is in normal. And if the window is stretched then i want to stretch all the items with it's "auto" size (means i want to show full of scrollviewer's items). Need help please

Comment: You mean I should put that Binding Height and Width in the Scroll viewer's section. Sorry I'm not pro but I tried put those your suggestions everywhere, but i couldn't see the change. I also updated with picture help please. And Thank you sir.

Comment: Oh no i can't post with picture cause i haven't enough reputation score. Can you please see this image below? 
http://i42.tinypic.com/10r7994.png

Comment: Somebody Answer to The posted Picture Please??

Comment: which one there are two Scrollviewer in the picture?

Comment: both, bcs you want to change the height/width of both according to window's height/width.